# Bind second level of nested arrays in XAML on Windows 8

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to bind a two-level-nested array to a XAML control in a Windows 8 Metro-style App. The array looks like (with A, B, C being the elements of the top-level array)

```
A
--W
--X
B
--Y
C
--Z
```

and I want to bind a property of `W`, `X`, `Y` and `Z`.
What's the recommended way for achieving this? Should I use an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) (which results in much code)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can use LINQ's SelectMany() in a property and report PropertyChanged. Something like this:

```
private string[][] _my2DArray;
public string[][] My2DArray
{
    get { return _my2DArray; }
    set 
    { 
        _my2DArray = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("My2DArray");
        OnPropertyChanged("InternalArrays");
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> InternalArrays
{
    get { return _my2DArray.SelectMany(a => a); }
}
```

You may want to consider using an ObservableCollection instead of an array to notify changes within the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think it doesn't answer my question. My problem is that I'm unable to bind to a property of **all** the elements in the second level array. On other platforms (not Windows 8) it's possible to use an XPath expression as binding (see [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/436779/1641070)). But that's not possible on Win8.